# How to store files on Airflow and then write to GCS?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to make a pipeline, where I need to call a API and write the responses to a json file as `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`.
Then I want it to move that file to gcs.

As I am working on my shell, it is using my local disk but I want to schedule this process using Airflow. As file size is around 1 GB for a Week period, I don't think it's a good idea to keep files on Airflow. Can anyone suggest some good approach?

I am expecting that the json response is written to a file and that file is moved to GCS.

Comment: Why do you need to do that with `Airflow` ?

Answer (score 0):

> I dont think its not good idea to keep files on Airflow

Airflow is workflow manager it is not a storage layer thus files are stored only for compute propose while tasks are executed. Tasks should remove the files when finished (ideally by using `NamedTemporaryFile` thus this happens automatically)

You have several options.

1. In general it is not recommended to do disk/compute intensive jobs on Airflow workers but that recommendation is based on the assumption that Airflow workers are not designed to do this kind of tasks. Should you want you can configure high intensive disk/compute workers and route your tasks to these workers. I can't say that I recommend this as a rule but it is possible (and sometimes preferred due to simplicity).
2. As improvement to (1) you can utilize EC2/GCE machine or equivalent service of other cloud providers to do the heavy lifting. In that case your pipeline would be:

   start GCE machine -> download data to GCE -> load from GCE to GCS -> terminate GCE machine
3. As improvement to (2) assuming you have enough memory in the machine you can load data directly in memory to GCS (without storing data on disc)
   That can be done by using [GcsHook.download_as_byte_array](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/3374fdfcbddb630b4fc70ceedd5aed673e6c0a0d/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs.py#L352)
   then your pipeline can be:

   start GCE machine -> get data to GCE and load to GCS -> terminate GCE machine

You can decide on [writing operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#creating-a-custom-operator) `YourApiToGcs` to be used in several pipelines or write a Python callable to be used with [PythonOperator/ Taskflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonoperator).